# Is valid XML also valid HTML

Tags: html, xml

I'm trying to convert some XML to HTML. The XML contains only a few known elements that map to HTML tags. Do I need to html encode text nodes?

Is valid XML also valid HTML assuming we are only using HTML tags?

Comment: You should read up on XHTML

Comment: Basicly yes. Read about XHTML to catch on exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is valid<sup>*</sup> XML also valid HTML assuming we are only using HTML tags?

*<sub>Note that *"valid"* is not the same as *"well-formed"*. Validity is a property that requires well-formedness and succesful comparison against a DTD or schema. Well-formedness only means syntactical correctness, which is what you mean here.</sub>

Yes. HTML uses a few conventions that are not present in XML (prominently unclosed tags, unencoded tag bodies like `<script>`, namespaces are unsupported, incorrect tag nesting is glossed over) but all things considered well-formed, vanilla (!) XML that only uses HTML tag names will be understood by an HTML parser.

Vanilla means in this case: No custom DTDs, no custom named character entities.

> Do I need to html encode text nodes?

No. All characters valid in a certain encoding (say, UTF-8) will be acceptable in both XML and HTML, as long as the encoding is correctly declared. Character escaping schemes are compatible, so e.g. `&#160;` (or `&xA0;`) will represent a non-breaking space in both XML and HTML. Writing that non-breaking space verbatim (i.e as single byte `xA0`) into the text will work as well. *Named* character entities besides `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, `&quot;` and `&apos;` are unsupported in XML, whereas all *numbered* character entities XML could use will work in HTML. That means you will not encounter a problem there.

XML that does not declare an encoding will default to UTF-8. You should not have a problem with leaving all text nodes and attribute values as they are **as long as** you use the same encoding for your HTML.

Answer (score 3):

> Is valid XML also valid HTML assuming we are only using HTML tags?

No. Here's a simple example.

```
<div>
  <span/>
</div>
```

This is well-formed and valid XML. It is not valid HTML (except when processed as XHTML) in any version of HTML.

That's not to say that a HTML parser won't process it, but that's not a good test. An HTML parser will process *any* byte sequence, valid or not.

Comment: +1 Strictly speaking you are right, an HTML validator will complain about the missing end tag of the span. Depending on the HTML parser this could indeed result in an incorrectly built DOM tree and subsequent layout issues.